# Создать один экземпляр и экспортировать его много раз

Tags: node.js, модули, mvp, sequelize.js

Занимаюсь сейчас разработкой бекенд-приложения, api. У меня есть ORM Sequelize и, соответственно, модели для представления разных таблиц. Создание модели выглядит примерно так:

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize');

class User extends Model {}

User.init({
  // Model attributes are defined here
  firstName: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  lastName: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
    // allowNull defaults to true
  }
}, {
  // Other model options go here
  sequelize, // We need to pass the connection instance
  modelName: 'User' // We need to choose the model name
});
```

Ситуация в том, что эту модель мне надо экспортировать в разных сервисах. И при том я явно не могу написать `module.exports = User`, потому что в таком случае я буду много раз создавать одну и ту же модель. А это, вроде как, не есть желательное поведение.

Как я могу создать объект единожды, а потом экспортировать его экземпляр много раз?

Comment: Почему много раз? Один. Инициализация то один раз происходит, потом уже всё кэшируется NodeJs и отдается просто ссылка. Можете проверить добавив вывод console.log('User model created') после вызова `User.init`

Comment: @Anatoly О, да, спасибо большое. Не знал, что это так работает. Сейчас нашёл ответ на такой же вопрос на англойязычном stackoverflow, уже думал отвечать на собственный вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Инициализация происходит один раз, потом уже всё кэшируется NodeJs и отдается просто ссылка. Можете проверить добавив вывод console.log('User model created') после вызова User.init